# Calculated rows based on Total row and sub total row

Tags: pandas, percentage

How do we calculate top n rows contributing 80 % to Total?

```
Item Number Item    Amount  State
1   Agriculture, forestry and fishing   308507  Oregon
--
10  Gross State Domestic Product
```

More data is in the file located in gdrive:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=10l84MVcIDIwyWyKa_ftEYrNDwB0C3HWS

I have the following code to calculate top n contributing rows

```
for col in cols:
    PercentageCol = col + ' %'
    result_pivot[PercentageCol] = round((result_pivot[col] / result_pivot['Gross State Domestic Product']) * 100,2)

cols = result_pivot.columns[result_pivot.columns.str.contains('%')]

result_pivot  = result_pivot[cols].T
result_pivot['Avg'] = round(result_pivot.mean(axis=1), 2)

result_pivot = result_pivot.sort_values(['Avg'], ascending=False)
result_pivot = result_pivot.nlargest(5, columns='Avg')
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The top 80% based on the sort we see now, or do we have to sort `descending` so we have the `Amount` column from big to small?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, we have two scenario's. With and without sorting:

## 1 Without sorting descending:

We can calculate the percentage with `Amount / sum of Amount`. Then we calculate the cumulative sum of those values and filter with Boolean indexing all rows that are smaller than `0.8` which is `80%`:

```
df_80 = df[(df['Amount'] / df['Amount'].sum()).cumsum() < 0.8]

print(df_80)
    Item Number                                               Item  \
0           1.0                  Agriculture, forestry and fishing   
1           1.1                                              Crops   
2           1.2                                          Livestock   
3           1.3                               Forestry and logging   
4           1.4                            Fishing and aquaculture   
5           2.0                               Mining and quarrying   
6           3.0                                      Manufacturing   
7           4.0  Electricity, gas, water supply & other utility...   
8           5.0                                       Construction   
9           6.0              Trade, repair, hotels and restaurants   
10          6.1                            Trade & repair services   
11          6.2                               Hotels & restaurants   
12          7.0  Transport, storage, communication & services r...   
13          7.1                                           Railways   
14          7.2                                     Road transport   
15          7.3                                    Water transport   
16          7.4                                      Air transport   
17          7.5                   Services incidental to transport   
18          7.6                                            Storage   
19          7.7   Communication & services related to broadcasting   
20          8.0                                 Financial services   
21          9.0  Real estate, ownership of dwelling & professio...   
22         10.0                              Public administration   
23         11.0                                     Other services   
24         12.0                         TOTAL GSVA at basic prices   
25         13.0                                  Taxes on Products   
26         14.0                              Subsidies on products   
27         15.0                       Gross State Domestic Product   
28         16.0                                   Population ('00)   
29         17.0                              Per Capita GSDP (Rs.)   
..          ...                                                ...   
54         12.0                         TOTAL GSVA at basic prices   
55         13.0                                  Taxes on Products   
56         14.0                              Subsidies on products   
57         15.0                       Gross State Domestic Product   
58         16.0                                   Population ('00)   
59         17.0                              Per Capita GSDP (Rs.)   
60          1.0                  Agriculture, forestry and fishing   
61          1.1                                              Crops   
62          1.2                                          Livestock   
63          1.3                               Forestry and logging   
64          1.4                            Fishing and aquaculture   
65          2.0                               Mining and quarrying   
66          3.0                                      Manufacturing   
67          4.0  Electricity, gas, water supply & other utility...   
68          5.0                                       Construction   
69          6.0              Trade, repair, hotels and restaurants   
70          6.1                           Trade & repair services*   
71          6.2                               Hotels & restaurants   
72          7.0  Transport, storage, communication & services r...   
73          7.1                                           Railways   
74          7.2                                   Road transport**   
75          7.3                                    Water transport   
76          7.4                                      Air transport   
77          7.5                   Services incidental to transport   
78          7.6                                            Storage   
79          7.7   Communication & services related to broadcasting   
80          8.0                                 Financial services   
81          9.0  Real estate, ownership of dwelling & professio...   
82         10.0                              Public administration   
83         11.0                                     Other services   

        Amount       State  
0     308507.0      Oregon  
1     140421.0      Oregon  
2      30141.0      Oregon  
3      15744.0      Oregon  
4     122201.0      Oregon  
5       3622.0      Oregon  
6    1177608.0      Oregon  
7     204110.0      Oregon  
8     165819.0      Oregon  
9     380927.0      Oregon  
10    343492.0      Oregon  
11     37434.0      Oregon  
12    189656.0      Oregon  
13     15649.0      Oregon  
14     46171.0      Oregon  
15     17820.0      Oregon  
16     46359.0      Oregon  
17     19272.0      Oregon  
18       357.0      Oregon  
19     44028.0      Oregon  
20    233618.0      Oregon  
21    407099.0      Oregon  
22    346486.0      Oregon  
23    180431.0      Oregon  
24   3597882.0      Oregon  
25    527279.0      Oregon  
26     61854.0      Oregon  
27   4063307.0      Oregon  
28     14950.0      Oregon  
29    271793.0      Oregon  
..         ...         ...  
54  39828404.0  Washington  
55   4985670.0  Washington  
56   1067867.0  Washington  
57  43746207.0  Washington  
58    266620.0  Washington  
59    164077.0  Washington  
60   5930617.0       Idaho  
61   3070386.0       Idaho  
62   1656104.0       Idaho  
63    499808.0       Idaho  
64    704319.0       Idaho  
65    558824.0       Idaho  
66   4273567.0       Idaho  
67    482470.0       Idaho  
68   7314003.0       Idaho  
69   8557345.0       Idaho  
70   7763847.0       Idaho  
71    793498.0       Idaho  
72   4020934.0       Idaho  
73    147897.0       Idaho  
74   2761427.0       Idaho  
75     26956.0       Idaho  
76    125029.0       Idaho  
77     71567.0       Idaho  
78      3290.0       Idaho  
79    884767.0       Idaho  
80   2010306.0       Idaho  
81   7287633.0       Idaho  
82   2068915.0       Idaho  
83   5728645.0       Idaho
```

## 2. With sorting

```
df_80 = df[(df['Amount'] / df['Amount'].sum()).sort_values(ascending=False).cumsum() < 0.8]

print(df_80)
    Item Number                                               Item  \
30          1.0                  Agriculture, forestry and fishing   
36          3.0                                      Manufacturing   
39          6.0              Trade, repair, hotels and restaurants   
51          9.0  Real estate, ownership of dwelling & professio...   
54         12.0                         TOTAL GSVA at basic prices   
55         13.0                                  Taxes on Products   
57         15.0                       Gross State Domestic Product   
60          1.0                  Agriculture, forestry and fishing   
68          5.0                                       Construction   
69          6.0              Trade, repair, hotels and restaurants   
70          6.1                           Trade & repair services*   
81          9.0  Real estate, ownership of dwelling & professio...   
83         11.0                                     Other services   
84         12.0                         TOTAL GSVA at basic prices   
85         13.0                                  Taxes on Products   
87         15.0                       Gross State Domestic Product   

        Amount       State  
30   8015238.0  Washington  
36   7756921.0  Washington  
39   4986319.0  Washington  
51   6970183.0  Washington  
54  39828404.0  Washington  
55   4985670.0  Washington  
57  43746207.0  Washington  
60   5930617.0       Idaho  
68   7314003.0       Idaho  
69   8557345.0       Idaho  
70   7763847.0       Idaho  
81   7287633.0       Idaho  
83   5728645.0       Idaho  
84  48233259.0       Idaho  
85   5189352.0       Idaho  
87  52600230.0       Idaho
```